# Can't install Quickly on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: application-development, quickly

I'dd like to learn linux development so I tried to install Quickly.
Followed instructions from this page 'https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Quickly#Installation", but my system says "Unable to locate package quickly".

What options are there?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I know nothing about Quickly, and haven't heard of it before, however looking at the bottom of the wiki page, it was last edited "*2013-02-01*" which was long ago, so I'm betting it's *out-of-date*, possibly related to GTK+2 to other depreciated tools (even Didier Roches' (didrocks)  referenced blogs were gone.

Comment: Ouch. That page is from 2013. Quickly development stopped years ago, and the package was dropped before 16.04.